# Получить текст из ячейки добавленной в таблицу строки JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Имеется следующий код:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.table tr').hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('hover');
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
    });

    $('.table tr').click(function(){
        $('.table tr').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    $fordel=$(this).children('td:last-child').text();
    $fordell=$(this).children('td:first-child').text();
    alert($fordel);
    });
});


function Geeks() {
row = $("<tr id='5'></tr>");
                col1 = $("<td>5</td>");
            
                row.append(col1).prependTo("#myTable");
               }
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>

<table id="myTable" class="table">
  <tr id="1"><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr id="2"><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr id="3"><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr id="4"><td>4</td></tr>
</table> 


<a class="delete" href="#" onclick='Geeks()'>Добавить</a>
```

По клику на изначальные строки таблицы получаем текст из ячейки в алёрт. Однако, скрипт не работает для новой добавленной строки. Как исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Напишите обработчики через делегирование:

```
$(document).on('hover', '.table tr', function()
```

И

```
$(document).on('click', '.table tr', function()
```

Если `table` никогда не добавляется динамически, то вместо `document` можно написать его, и тогда в селекторе далее писать только `tr`

Comment: Всё получилось, только стиль для hover пропал почему-то, для нажатого стиль применяется.

Comment: Да, т.к. это уже не сам метод, а делегирование события, то надо его переписать чуть по-другому. Я бы применил mouseenter и mouseleave